# Creating a sidebar with javascript and jquery that cycles divs simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery

first of all, I'm new to programming and english is my second lanuage so be a little bit more tolerant! Now, I'm trying to create a side bar with html/javascript/jquery with not much success..
the examples are pretty self explanatory.
This is what I've come up with; 
html code;

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <ul id="side-rcnt-thumb-post-list">

        <li>
            <div id="content-1">include title 1</div>
            <div id="content-2">include title 2</div>
            <div id="content-3">include title 3</div>
            <div id="content-4">include title 4</div>
            <div id="content-5">include title 5</div>
            <div id="content-6">include title 6</div>
            <div id="content-7">include title 7</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div id="content-1">include title 1</div>
            <div id="content-2">include title 2</div>
            <div id="content-3">include title 3</div>
            <div id="content-4">include title 4</div>
            <div id="content-5">include title 5</div>
            <div id="content-6">include title 6</div>
            <div id="content-7">include title 7</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div id="content-1">include title 1</div>
            <div id="content-2">include title 2</div>
            <div id="content-3">include title 3</div>
            <div id="content-4">include title 4</div>
            <div id="content-5">include title 5</div>
            <div id="content-6">include title 6</div>
            <div id="content-7">include title 7</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div id="content-1">include title 1</div>
            <div id="content-2">include title 2</div>
            <div id="content-3">include title 3</div>
            <div id="content-4">include title 4</div>
            <div id="content-5">include title 5</div>
            <div id="content-6">include title 6</div>
            <div id="content-7">include title 7</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div id="content-1">include title 1</div>
            <div id="content-2">include title 2</div>
            <div id="content-3">include title 3</div>
            <div id="content-4">include title 4</div>
            <div id="content-5">include title 5</div>
            <div id="content-6">include title 6</div>
            <div id="content-7">include title 7</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div id="content-1">include title 1</div>
            <div id="content-2">include title 2</div>
            <div id="content-3">include title 3</div>
            <div id="content-4">include title 4</div>
            <div id="content-5">include title 5</div>
            <div id="content-6">include title 6</div>
            <div id="content-7">include title 7</div>
        </li>
    </ul>




</div>
```

my basic javascript+jquery code;

```
    var divs = $('div[id^="content-"]').hide(),
    i = 0;

(function cycle() {

    divs.eq(i).fadeIn(400)
        .delay(1000)
        .fadeOut(400, cycle);

    i = ++i % divs.length;

})();
```

[This is an example of how it works now;][1]

[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/9020cew0/ 
And how it SHOULD work; 
It should simultaneously AND separately cycle the li's, for example 
second 1; it shows "include title 1" 6 times 
second 2; it shows "include title 2" 6 times 
 etc... you get the point!
Every time I try something...it just gets messy, I'm confused...
 thanks in advance..

Comment: you need to have seperate ids for all li divs. check my fiddle for better idea. https://jsfiddle.net/msyy0L41/

Comment: yes I tried that too but see for yourself, your code doesn't work properly, after "include title 7" it gets messed up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've removed the transitions from this version, simply to remove factors of complication. I'm not messing with a counter, it isn't absolutely necessary. If any div has more elements than another, it will not break -- each LI is treated separately. It's available as a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/snowMonkey/msyy0L41/1/), or see below:

```js
var divs = $('div[id^="content-"]').hide();

cycle();

function cycle() {
  $("li").children(":visible").hide().next().show();
  if ($("li").children(":visible").length == 0) {
    $("li").children(":first-child").show();
  }
  setTimeout(cycle, 500);
}
```

```css
    #sidebar{
        width: 250px;
        margin-left:50%;
    }



    /*
    Style Sidebar Recent Blog Posts with 75x75px Thumbnails
    */
    ul#side-rcnt-thumb-post-list {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #side-rcnt-thumb-post-list li {
        margin-top: 15px;
        overflow: hidden;
        border-top: 1px solid #CCC;
        padding-top: 15px;
        position: relative;
        min-height: 76px;
    }


    .srtpl-l {
        float: left;
        margin-right: 15px;
    }

    .srtpl-a {
        display: block;
        outline: 0!important;
        font-weight: 400;
    }

    #side-rcnt-thumb-post-list img {
        max-width: 100%;
        width: auto\9;
        height: auto;
        vertical-align: middle;
        border: 0;
        -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
    }

    .srtpl-r {
        margin-left: 90px;
    }


    .srtpl-n {
        display: block;
        color: #343534;
        line-height: 1.2;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 13px;
        outline: 0!important;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: "Open Sans","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="sidebar">
    <ul id="side-rcnt-thumb-post-list">

        <li>
            <div id="content-1">include title 1</div>
            <div id="content-2">include title 2</div>
            <div id="content-3">include title 3</div>
            <div id="content-4">include title 4</div>
            <div id="content-5">include title 5</div>
            <div id="content-6">include title 6</div>
            <div id="content-7">include title 7</div>
        </li>
        <li>
             <div id="content-11">include title 1</div>
            <div id="content-22">include title 2</div>
            <div id="content-33">include title 3</div>
            <div id="content-44">include title 4</div>
            <div id="content-55">include title 5</div>
            <div id="content-66">include title 6</div>
            <div id="content-77">include title 7</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div id="content-1">include title 1</div>
            <div id="content-2">include title 2</div>
            <div id="content-3">include title 3</div>
            <div id="content-4">include title 4</div>
            <div id="content-5">include title 5</div>
            <div id="content-6">include title 6</div>
            <div id="content-7">include title 7</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div id="content-1">include title 1</div>
            <div id="content-2">include title 2</div>
            <div id="content-3">include title 3</div>
            <div id="content-4">include title 4</div>
            <div id="content-5">include title 5</div>
            <div id="content-6">include title 6</div>
            <div id="content-7">include title 7</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div id="content-1">include title 1</div>
            <div id="content-2">include title 2</div>
            <div id="content-3">include title 3</div>
            <div id="content-4">include title 4</div>
            <div id="content-5">include title 5</div>
            <div id="content-6">include title 6</div>
            <div id="content-7">include title 7</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div id="content-1">include title 1</div>
            <div id="content-2">include title 2</div>
            <div id="content-3">include title 3</div>
            <div id="content-4">include title 4</div>
            <div id="content-5">include title 5</div>
            <div id="content-6">include title 6</div>
            <div id="content-7">include title 7</div>
        </li>
    </ul>




</div>
```

Comment: Wow, that's funky. Changed the show/hide to fadeout/fadein, got this https://jsfiddle.net/snowMonkey/msyy0L41/2/

Comment: Heh. Tinkered a little more, this looks SO much better: https://jsfiddle.net/msyy0L41/3/

Comment: Well, crud. Time limit on editing comments kicked in. But the same as above, commented and annotated all over the place: https://jsfiddle.net/msyy0L41/4/

Comment: thanks sir, it works great on it's own but when I include it to my page it messes with other li elements for example the navigation bar...

Comment: Yeah, fix is pretty simple, just put a .class selector https://jsfiddle.net/7qvbajej/ ! Great work sir!